# ¿Como filtrar por ciudad en Google Place Autocomplete?

Tags: android

Estoy utilizando en un `EditText Google Place Autocomplete`, para buscar las calles de una ciudad, por el momento lo filtre por País de la siguiente Manera:

```
AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new 
AutocompleteFilter.Builder() **.setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY) 
.setCountry("AR")** .build();*
```

Pero necesito que esta búsqueda sea aun mas filtrada, que sea por una ciudad especifica, intente realizarlo con `TYPE_POSTAL_CODE` pero no logro implementarlo.

Comment: puedes usar el TYPE_FILTER_CITIES

Comment: De que manera implemento este filtro?

Comment: te dire, no he implementado ese tipo de cosas, y por lo tanto no lo puse como respuesta. lo busque, en este [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.Builder) supongo lo habras utilizado, pero hasta abajo viene que lo puedes imlpementar tal y como ya lo tienes `setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas restringir el conjunto de resultados de una solicitud a ciudades.

usa la constante:

> **[TYPE_FILTER_CITIES](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter#TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)** : Devuelve cualquier resultado que coincida con los siguientes tipos de lugares:
>
> - **TYPE_LOCALITY**
> - **TYPE_ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_3**

ejemplo:

```
setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
```

---

Los valores validos para [**setTypeFilter()**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.Builder.html#setTypeFilter(int)) son:

- [TYPE_FILTER_NONE](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html#TYPE_FILTER_NONE)
- [TYPE_FILTER_GEOCODE](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html#TYPE_FILTER_GEOCODE)
- [TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html#TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
- [TYPE_FILTER_ESTABLISHMENT](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html#TYPE_FILTER_ESTABLISHMENT)
- [TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html#TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS)
- [TYPE_FILTER_CITIES](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html#TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)